# After changing PHP version the Joomla cms has "Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: /var/lib/php/sessions)"

Tags: php, joomla

After doing this on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/dirk# sudo a2enmod php7.2
root@ubuntu:/home/dirk# systemctl restart apache2
```

Joomla 3.9.16 (with maximum error log) shows at the browser then:

> Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: /var/lib/php/sessions) in /var/www/so-geht-es/libraries/joomla/session/handler/native.php on line 260
>   Error: Failed to start application: Failed to start the session

What to change PHP because of this message within the backend of Joomla:

> Error
>
> We have detected that your server is using PHP 7.1.33-12+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 which is obsolete and no longer receives official security updates by its developers. The Joomla! Project recommends upgrading your site to PHP 7.2 or later which will receive security updates at least until 2020-11-30. Please ask your host to make PHP 7.2 or a later version the default version for your site. If your host is already PHP 7.2 ready please enable PHP 7.2 on your site's root and 'administrator' directories – typically you can do this yourself through a tool in your hosting control panel, but it's best to ask your host if you are unsure."

But with PHP 7.2 I get the error mentioned.
How am I able to figure out what causes this issue?

Comment: Since you aren't getting any feedback here, you might try [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did not install MySQLi 7.3, had to do additionaly

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-mysqli
```

Current Joomla needs the MySQLi for database connectivity

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when upgrading from 7.2 to 7.4.

Apparently this problem arises for a lot of different reasons, but in my case it was happening because I'd installed the core 7.4 package, but not some of the bonus packages.

So I did a `dpkg -l | grep -i php` and then installed the 7.4 version of every package that came up.

I don't know which were important, but by the time I'd finished typing `sudo apt-get install php7.4-zip` I had my website back.  Huzzah!